# No output on a Playa Low Variable

Tags: playa, relationships, low-variables, transcribe

I can't work this out and probably just need another set of eyes.

I have a Low Variable name lv_book_slider_en which is a Playa field looking up a channel with specific category.

There are channel entries assigned to the LV, and the status is open.

When I call the variable as `{lv_book_slider_en}` within my template it spits out:

```
[285] [a-southern-girl-a-small-town-and-the-secret-of-a-good-life] A Southern Girl, a Small Town, and the Secret of a Good Life
[448] [blue-like-jazz-the-movie] Blue Like Jazz: The Movie
[4925] [a_call_to_action] A Call to Action
[5068] [antinomianism] Antinomianism
```

When I try to do:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_book_slider_en"}

{title}
                                              {/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

I get nothing.

I've just found as I typed this that Transcribe seems to be the problem. If I disable that, I get output as expected. I know Transcribe builds relationships between language entries.

Unfortunately, right now, Transcribe is a core part of the build so can't really look to move.

Does anyone have insight here?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use the `playa:children` tag instead of the Parse tag:

```
{exp:playa:children var="lv_book_slider_en"}
    {title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: sadly not, think I'll run this one by the guys at EEHarbor as that seems to be where the issue lies.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to this, I had to put transcribe=“disable” inside of the Playa tag (not the ece loop) to get it to output. Credit goes to EE Harbor.